# Using Perl PAR:Packer exe -s command line inputs

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, packer

I frequently use the perl `-s` option for command line inputs to my scripts. Now, I want to convert some of these to exe files using `PAR::packer`. Is there a way I can use this style of command line input with the exe files?

For example, I would run a perl script as:

```
perl my_script.pl -name="Robin" -date=20130201
```

In this script, the variables `$name`, and `$date` would be initialized with the given values. Can I emulate this behavior with the exe file that I create from my_script (using `PAR::packer`)?

Comment: I don't know but I'd strongly suggest switching to `Getopt::Long` instead.

Comment: I second the Getopt::Long comment. The `-s` flag is rudimentary at best.

Comment: agreed - I have switched to using Getopt and everything works fine. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like that at the beginning of your scripts:

```
BEGIN{ 
    my %args = map {s/^-{0,2}//; split /[=:]/} @ARGV;
    no strict 'refs';
    $$_ = $args{$_} for keys %args;
    @ARGV = ();
}
```

Or put it in a package you "use" at start of your scripts.

EDIT: changed local=>my, simplify maps and add no strict 'refs' as sugested.

Comment: You don't want to do that. ① do `my %args = ...`. `local` seems weird here. ② `map +(do{...}),...` ⇔ `map do{...},...` ⇔ `map {...} ...`! ③ This requires `no strict 'refs'`. ④ This is evil, but `perl -Mstrict -E'@main::{qw/x y z/}=map \$_,(1..3); say for our($x, $y, $z)'` works too, even under strict refs :) Also, no chance that this is mistaken for regular references…